# CSS Bootstrap: height of row becoming 1px after adding pull-right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want grid which is centered and takes half of the screen on `sm`, `md` and `lg` devices, and takes full screen on `xs` devices.  So I have this layout:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3" >
            <a href="#" >
                <img class="img-responsive pull-right" src="/images/logo.png">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This layout works good on `sm` and larger devices. But when I'm trying to run it on `xs` device (actually using Chrome simulator) my `col-md-6`  takes 100% width as expected, but also it has 1 px height. I.e. logo is visible, but block `div` itself has 1 px height, so I don't see any background of that `col-sm-6` DIV.  I understand that root of the problem is  `pull-right` class on my logo, but don't know how to solve it.

- So, what I'm doing wrong here?
- And is it good layout for having 100% width on mobiles and 50% (centered) on other screens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `class=col-xs-12` otherwise according to bootstrap stylesheet the div height would be 1px for small devices. Otherwise you need to set the height of the div separately see

**snippet**

```css
.fr_bckgrnd {
        background: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/1526/dark-blur-blurred-gradient.jpg");
       }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      
       <style type="text/css">
       

    
       </style>
       <script type="text/javascript">
        
       </script>
       </head>
       <body>
       
       
      <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-12 fr_bckgrnd" >
            <a href="#" >
                <img class="img-responsive pull-right" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Small_Flag_of_the_United_Nations_ZP.svg/488px-Small_Flag_of_the_United_Nations_ZP.svg.png">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

After using this code check in the developer tool the width is 100%.